# What is the motivation behind the naming of quantum double theory?

Tags: quantum-information, terminology

I am reading Kitaev's [famous toric code paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021). In it, Kitaev gave an algebraic construction of his model. This algebraic construction is called quantum double. After reading the reference therein on the quantum double, I still don't quite understand why it is called "quantum double." Could someone briefly enlighten me on why people call it "quantum double"? In what sense it is a double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology is a bit like a "[Quantum Goup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group)" which is  neither "quantum" nor a "group."

A [quantum double](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfel%27d+double) is a standard way (due to Drinfeld I think)  of constructing a [Hopf algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra) (a bialgebra with antipode etc) from a group algebra. It's a "double" in the sense that the double $D(H)$ combines  both the group algebra $H(G)$ of a finite group $G$ and its dual $H^*(G)$.  An element $g\in G$ has a projector function  $P_g\in H^*(g)$ assigned to it so that $P_gP_{g'}=\delta_{gg'}P_g$  and, just as an element of the group algebra is a linear combination of $g$'s,  a general element of $D(H)$ is alinear combination of  the $P_g {h}$. There    there is a *product* $\nabla:(D\otimes D)\to D$
defined by
$$
\nabla(P_g h \otimes P_{g'}h') = \delta_{g, hg'h^{-1}} P_g hh'
$$
and a *coproduct* $\Delta: D\to D\otimes D$ given by
$$
\Delta(P_hg)= \sum_{h=h'h''} P_{h'}g\otimes P_{h''} g
$$

If this does not seem very helpful, I am sympathetic. It took me a long time to figure out Hopf algebras, and I am still not comfortable with them.

Unless you are into category theory, the  Toric Code is best studied as it is presented in the physics literature.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your advice! This is an answer I was hoping for! Thank you so much for such a detailed answer!